# how to use "{% include 'a.html '%}" in a javascript expression on google-app-engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, include

this is my code:

```
$('.left').html("{% include 'foot.html' %}")
```

it will show error ,

so how to make it running.

thanks

Comment: @George - I'm guessing `foot.html` has double quotes in there, which would throw a JavaScript syntax error, that'd be my bet at least.

Comment: @zjm1126 - You need to clarify your question. What's happening? Where's the error thrown? What does the error say?

Comment: @zjm1126: How many times are going to post 'how to make it running' questions without posting any details about the error? This is characteristic of ALL of your questions of StackOverflow, and I'm personally kind of sick of it.

Comment: I agree with @Adam. @zjm1126 please consider contributing to this site instead of just periodically throwing your problems at it hoping for someone to solve your problems for you.

Comment: thanks everyone,  i will be try  .

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to do anything if your JavaScript isn't processed by webapp or Django before it gets sent to the client because the templating pseudo-language that they use will only work *server-side.* You'll also want to make sure you use the `|safe` filter or your HTML will get escaped; from what I can infer from the (very little) code you supplied this isn't the desired behavior.